# Struggling to show data from javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, api

Note: I am new to JavaScript and html so there are a lot of things i do not quite understand yet.

I am trying to make a web-application that uses a bus-schedule API to show the bus times around my apartment. I have managed to retrieve the data, but I struggle to display that data in the html. (edit: it is possibly a SDK, i dont really know the difference)

```js
// this is the function write_bus() in my javascript file departures.js:
function write_bus() {
  document.getElementById("bustime-kong").innerHTML = data;
}

// 'data' is a variable in javascript that contains the information I fetched from the client, and is what I am trying to show.It is on the following format:
const data = {
  aimedArrivalTime: '2022-01-06T12:36:00+0100',
  aimedDepartureTime: '2022-01-06T12:36:00+0100',
  cancellation: false,
  date: '2022-01-06',
  destinationDisplay: {
    frontText: 'xxx'
  },
  expectedDepartureTime: '2022-01-06T12:38:12+0100',
  expectedArrivalTime: '2022-01-06T12:37:32+0100',
  forAlighting: true,
  forBoarding: true,
  notices: [],
  predictionInaccurate: false,
  quay: {
    id: 'xxx',
    name: 'xxx',
    publicCode: 'P2',
    situations: [],
    stopPlace: [Object]
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="departures.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="write_bus()" value="Busstider"> <br>
<div id="bustime-kong"></div>
```

(In order to save some space i removed 2/3 of the data)

I appreciate every bit of help i could get!

Comment: If `data` contains the response already parsed into an object, using it like you did will simply print `[object Object]`. You need to access the individual values. If `data` is an array and the above is the first element, you can use `data[0].quay.id` to get 'xxx' for instance. Also: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)

Comment: You can't simply display a whole data sctructure by assigning it to a div. It's more complex than that. You have to "explore" your data structure, list its key-value pairs, write loops, etc. There are many tutorials about that everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert raw objects like that as DOM text. You have to use specific properties, but if you are so inclined to insert object like that, use `JSON.stringify()` method.

```
document.getElementById("bustime-kong").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

BTW, It is good practice to put `<script>` tag at the end to make sure HTML is loaded before running any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will parse through the json and print it in table form like below.

```js
// this is the function write_bus() in my javascript file departures.js:
function write_bus() {
  document.getElementById("bustime-kong").innerHTML = createTable(data);
}

// 'data' is a variable in javascript that contains the information I fetched from the client, and is what I am trying to show.It is on the following format:
const data = {
  aimedArrivalTime: '2022-01-06T12:36:00+0100',
  aimedDepartureTime: '2022-01-06T12:36:00+0100',
  cancellation: false,
  date: '2022-01-06',
  destinationDisplay: {
    frontText: 'xxx'
  },
  expectedDepartureTime: '2022-01-06T12:38:12+0100',
  expectedArrivalTime: '2022-01-06T12:37:32+0100',
  forAlighting: true,
  forBoarding: true,
  notices: [],
  predictionInaccurate: false,
  quay: {
    id: 'xxx',
    name: 'xxx',
    publicCode: 'P2',
    situations: [],
    stopPlace: [Object]
  }
}

function createTable(data){

  var table = "<table>";
  for(var key in data){
    table+="<tr>";
    table+="<td>"+key+"</td>";
    table+="<td>"+data[key]+"</td>";
    table+="</tr>";
  }
  table+="</table>";
  return table;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="write_bus()" value="Busstider"> <br>
<div id="bustime-kong"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is array of data you need to use `Json.stringify` method,

```
document.getElementById("bustime-kong").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```